# Laravel change() method throws error with mysql 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, doctrine, homestead

I installed a fresh Laravel Homestead development environment (11.*) which ships with MySql 8, when I try to run migrations which have the `->change()`  method it throws the following error:

````
>Doctrine\DBAL\Exception  : An exception occurred while executing '
>```
>SELECT COLUMN_NAME AS Field, COLUMN_TYPE AS Type, IS_NULLABLE AS `Null`, COLUMN_KEY AS `Key`, COLUMN_DEFAULT AS `Default`, EXTRA AS Extra, COLUMN_COMMENT AS Comment, CHARACTER_SET_NAME AS CharacterSet, COLLATION_NAME AS Collation 
>FROM information_schema.COLUMNS 
>WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dummy' AND TABLE_NAME = 'dummy' 
>ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION ASC
>```
````

> ':

> Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::ensureForwardCompatibilityStatement(): Argument #1 ($stmt) must be of type Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\ResultStatement, PDOStatement given, called in /home/vagrant/code/eezee-b2b/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php on line 1314

This is the migration with the ->change() method:

```
    Schema::table('authentication', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('customer_uuid');
        $table->string('password')->change();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
```

After Googling like an idiot I'm still stuck, so I hope you guys can help me out.

Comment: Please post migration as well.

Comment: Check does: 1) The database `dummy` exists 2) The table `dummy` exists in this database 3) Your mysql account have enough privileges for to select from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Comment: @akina The answer to all of your questions is yes, previous migrations without the ```->change()```method run perfectly

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh.....I put the migration in the original question.

Comment: Add the facts into the question as update, not into a comment.

Comment: What are u changing is this migration than previous?

Comment: @PrashantDeshmukh..... I did'nt write the code but it supposedly changes the max chars of the varchar column

Comment: Here you need to have `authentication` table with all these columns then only you can run alter migration on it.